# Capturing openCV video in windows forms

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision, video-capture

When I try to capture video from webcam using **OpenCV**, it opens a new window and the video is shown there.

Instead of showing in a separate window, I want the video to be shown in a windows form element like picturebox.

I am using **visual c++ 2008** for developing windows forms. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider Emgu. It is a .NET wrapper for OpenCV which enables you to use almost every OpenCV features in .NET windows forms.